# PyYAML customized yaml processing

Tags: python, pyyaml

I would like to extend YAML with some custom macros so that I can "reuse" parts of definitions within the same file. Sample:

```
DEFAULTS:
- a
- b
- c
CUSTOM1:
- %DEFAULTS
- d
CUSTOM2:
- %DEFAULTS
- e
```

resulting in

```
CUSTOM1==['a','b','c','d']
CUSTOM2==['a','b','c','e']
```

Doesn't have to be exact same syntax, as long as I can get same functionality out of it. what are my options?

P.S. 
I do realize that it is possible to just walk the dictionary after parsing and re-adjust the values, however I'd like to do it while loading.

Answer (score 1):

There are no options within the YAML specification. The only thing that comes close is the [merge syntax](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html), but that is for merging mappings and doesn't work for sequences.

If you cannot switch to using mappings in your context (and use the `<<` merge), the cleanest way, IMO, to implement this is to make the values of `CUSTOM1` and `CUSTOM2` specific types, e.g. `expander`:

```
CUSTOM1: !expander
- %DEFAULTS
- d
```

that map to objects that interpret the first sequence element as a replaceable value when it starts with `%`.

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of PyYAML API hooks, however the code is not very well documented thus I have no idea which of the items are intended to be overwritten and to what effect.

Comment: @Droopy4096 If you want standard YAML mappings to behave differently and you don't want to postprocess the sequences than doing so in the parser is the only options. But the way PyYAML (and my derivative [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) theparser work is that they don't have the *context* to access to the value of the toplevel key referenced by `%DEFAULTS`. I would go for postprocessing, if you want to use default mappings (even though I know PyYAML internals pretty well).